# Laravel Dependency Injection and bindings

Tags: php, laravel, web, dependency-injection, frameworks

can anyone please clear the air for me! 
why do we need to implement an interface by a repository class and bind them in the service provider?? what's the use of the interface if it was binded with a specific class?? and if so, why can't we inject the repository itself in the controller? 
last thing, what is the dependency anyway? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The service provider binds service/repository to the application. It should be bind either with its Interface (which can then be used as property type for dependency injection) or its alias (such as 'foo.bar').

The disadvantage of using an alias is that the dependency MUST be the class itself, which the singleton is kept within the application. The advantage of using its Contract (interface) is that, following the IoC pattern, you can have the registered repository implementing the given Interface, allowing changes in vendor code, such as if you change the main Storage repository by replacing its service provider, the injection would still work if the singleton was registered with its main interface.

So if you intend to use some vendor (or your own code) to replace Laravel core feature, the dependencies injection wil still work, but by providing the vendor repository which implements the same contract as the Laravel one.